# Apache ExpiresDefault: can it reside in a <Location> directive?

Tags: apache-2.2

The 2.2 docs state that ExpiresDefault can be placed in server config, virtual host, directory, and .htaccess. It doesn't mention **Location**.

I have a mod_perl server, and I'd like most, or all, of the non-dynamic content (jpg, css, js, etc.) to expire "infrequently". But I want all mod_perl generated pages to expire "now".

My configuration appears to be working, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something, since it's undocumented.

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

<LocationMatch ^/app/.*>
  ExpiresDefault "now"
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Location>` falls under [**directory** context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context). So, yes.

Comment: Oh, wow, I never knew about contexts. Fantastic! Thanks!